# $f: [a,b]\to\Bbb R $. If $g(x)=\sup\{f(t):t∈[a,x]\}$ and $f$ is continuous , then prove that $g$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> $f: [a,b]\to\Bbb R $. If $g(x)=\sup\{f(t):t∈[a,x]\}$ and $f$ is continuous , then prove that $g$ is continuous at $a$.

My answer :

Because $f$ is continuous in $[a,b], f$ is continuous at $a$. So, you have that $$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to a} f(t)=f(a)$$

But $g(a)=\sup\{f(t):t\in[a,a]\}=\sup\{f(a)\}=f(a)$ $$\therefore g(a)=f(a)$$

Therefore, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=g(a)=f(a)$. So with this I know that

1) $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to a}f(t)=f(a)$ so $f$ is continuous at a ?

2) and it is $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to a}f(t)$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$?

Comment: Your proof is unreadable... and looks wrong in fact... I think that the key is to use that since $f$ is continuous, then for all $x\in [a,b]$ you have that $g(x)=f(c_x)$ for some $c_x\in [a,x]$. Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(c_x)=f(a)=g(a)$.

Comment: @surb can you explain what do you mean ?I need to show that g is continuous to a not in general

Comment: The exact proof is in my previous comment.

Comment: @Surb Maybe is it for all x∈[a,b] you have that g(x)=f(t) for some t∈[a,x] or not ?

Comment: Yes of course :-) A continuous function on a compact take its min and max... But the most important is that $t_x\to a$ when $x\to a$. Continuity of $f$ allow you to conclude.

Comment: @Surb Thank you.Can i ask you one thing for a continuous fuction ?

Comment: Please, don't ask if you can ask ! Just ask ;-)

Comment: Firts one thing for your answer.At limit of f(Cx) maybe it is Cx→a instad of x→a ?

Comment: @Surb . I am going to do with Tx but i tell this for others people that they will going to see the answer.

Comment: No it's not. $c_x\in [a,x]$. Therefore, when $x\to a$, then $c_x\to a$.

Comment: Ok i understand

Comment: @Surb  For f isn't continuous anywhere when f(X1)=f(X2)=y how did you prove it ? Do i take that it is continuous at X1 and X2 and i am going to  conclude in a error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f(t)$ is a continuous continous function over a closed interval, $f(t)$ achieves its maximum.

$g(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function.

For all $x_0$ in $[a,b)$

With $x > x_0$, either $f(t)$ achieves a new maximum in $[x_0, x]$ i.e. $\sup \{f(t): t\in [x_0,x]\} > \{f(t): t\in [a,x_0]\}$ in which case

$g(x) - g(x_0) < \sup \{f(t) - f(x_0): t\in[x_0,x]\}$

or it doesn't and

$g(x) - g(x_0) = 0$

In either case $|g(x) - g(x_0)| < \{f(t) - f(x_0): t\in[x_0,x]\}$

And, since f(t) is continuous, for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |g(x) - g(x_0)|\le |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$

and $g(x)$ is continuous

Comment: this will be the method for g(x) not g(a) that you need to find.But thank you

Comment: because this is a harded way to prove for the a

Comment: @Surb propably he was thinking for g in general not for a

Comment: @surb, I wanted to prove that $g$ was continuous over the interval, not just at $a$

Comment: Why the downvote? Doug's proof covers the OP's question, and much more.